# Browsing my website from proxy sites works but not from my own machine

Tags: iis, router, port-forwarding

I just setup my IIS to be accessible from web to be some IP : XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX. It works nicely when I visit from proxy sites like `hidemyass.com`. However, when I visit my website from my machine itself, I get my router's page instead of my website.

Why is it happening and how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is probably down to dns. Try running `nslookup` and see where the IP resolves. Also try running `tracert - traceroute` to see where the packets get routed.

Are you on the same local network as the server. It could be the fact you need to add local ip's into the dns.

Comment: @Scorian: Sorry I am not understanding what you are saying. Can you please explain more? I understand that is is because I am browsing from the same network as the website is hosted. But how do I solve this issue?

Comment: You need to setup your website to work on local DNS. I have the same setup. Tinydns does our external dns, Windows Server does our internal dns. When you write the external IP locally, it will return the router page. But when you write the domain or internal IP the website will resolve. So in short, you need to setup a A record in Windows DNS to resolve to your local ip not external. I'm guessing you are doing this on a internal network/same network as the server.

Comment: My IP is dynamic. Secondly, I am using Windows 7. Can this be done?